# Pendrive with CentOS Live USB not showing options to boot

Tags: centos, usb-flash-drive, liveusb

I downloaded CentOS DVD ISO and created a bootable NTFS USB pendrive using Live Linux install program.

When I was trying to install CentOS in my laptop using this pendrive, it booted from the pendrive and a CentOS menu list appeared, but the list contains only "Boot", "Boot from hard disk", "Boot from network" but no " Install CentOS" or "Try CentOS" options.

If I select "Boot" and enter nothing happens. If I select "Boot from hard disk" it's loading Windows 7 from the hard drive, what is the issue?

Comment: NTFS is likely the problem. Use Rufus or any other specific tool for that. Or format as FAT32 with boot flag and extract the ISO to it with 7Zip or similar.

Comment: And a suggestion for future questions: Use descriptive titles. Yours here is asking for a "so what?"

Comment: Thanks for your support. I formatted as FAT32 and made as Bootable pendrive for CentOS installation. This time the menu list appeared and its having "Install CentOS" option but when I select Install CentOS and Enter nothing is happening. I tried with Rufus and my pendrive is 16GB 3.0